# How to get data from range of column cells using Google Apps Script(GAS)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to get data from column A starting from cell A2 till cell A12. I try to use the following code but I keep getting error:

```
Cannot find method getDataRange(string). (line...
```

I don't want to use `range = sheet.getDataRange();` because that will copy
entire sheet values! How I can fix above error ?

```js
function getRangeData()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      range,
      values_array; 

  range = sheet.getDataRange('A2:A12');
  values_array = range.getValues();

  Logger.log(values_array);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getDataRange()` function has no parameters. ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getdatarange)) You need to dig some more to find an alternate way to accomplish your wish.

The function that you are looking for is `Sheet.getRange()`, which supports several ways to express the desired range, including [one that takes a string expressing a range in A1Notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation).

```js
function getRangeData()  {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet(),
      range,
      values_array; 

  range = sheet.getRange('A2:A12');
  values_array = range.getValues();

  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(values_array));
}
```